# AWS SAM Application: Python - Dynamically Adjust Schedule According to Daylight Saving Time Status

Tags: python, aws-lambda, dst, aws-sam

We have AWS SAM application that utilizes lambda functions scheduled to run at specific times. However, I've encountered an issue related to daylight saving time changes. When daylight saving time (DST) shifts occur, the schedule runs 1 hour later than intended. To address this issue, I'm exploring options to dynamically adjust the schedule based on whether DST is in effect or not, directly within the SAM template YAML file.

**My main question is: Is there a way to programmatically determine whether it's currently daylight saving time and adjust the schedule accordingly within the SAM template YAML?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.